# How to periodically execute a task in sprinboot by passing arguments

Tags: java, parameters, spring-data-jpa, arguments, scheduled-tasks

I want to execute a function periodically.First I need to save an object list to database. After save , I need to constantly monitor one of the object fields to see if its value changes. If that value changes in db ,I need to send a success response For this I need to pass the ids of the entity list to the monitoring function.All this happens in a single Api.

Comment: I think CronTrigger might help you. Or any other cron

Answer (score 0):

Does the @Scheduled annotation help you?

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000)
public void monitorOneOfTheObjectFields() {
    // monitoring logic here.
}
```

This method would have to retrieve the values from somewhere. You could store and retrieve them from a field in memory but this can cause problems with horizontal scaling. Storing those ids in a database (e.g. redis) would be another option.

Answer (score 0):

Add dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-quartz</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-boot-starter-quartz.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Coding a job:

```
@Component
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAsync
public class Job{
    
    @Async
    @Scheduled(initialDelay = 15000, fixedDelay = 300000)
    public void method() {
        // do something
    }
    
}
```

@Component : Indicates that this is a configuration, and @Configuration can also be used

@EnableScheduling
@Scheduled(initialDelay = 15000, fixedDelay = 300000)

initialDelay : start running this method 15000 millisecond after server startup
fixedDelay : then run this method every 300000 millisecond

@EnableAsync
@Async
if you need asynchronous execution, add them